# I cannot edit Excel file in Excel for Ipad - Convert buttons does nothing

Tags: ms-office, ipad

I have been trying to use a feature to open and edit Excel files from Dropbox app using Excel for iPad app.

I open the Excel file in this app, and I see a notice that I cannot edit the file but I have to convert it first

[image]

When I press `Convert and Edit`, nothing happens.

Does anyone have any idea why is nothing happenings and why I cannot edit Excel files?

PS. I opened .xslx file (office 2010)

Comment: Are your files stored on Dropbox for Business?  If so: 
http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_mobile-excel/excel-ipad-open-dropbox-files/0350513e-e157-4273-8eb7-f961bc83eb0f?auth=1

Comment: @nadyne Nope, just a regular free account. But I think I need to have Office 365 subscription to edit files, which I don't have

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted in the comments, editing is only allowed if one has a subscription to **Office 365**.
As noted in [this article](http://www.macworld.com/article/2139403/excel-for-ipad-review-the-best-spreadsheet-app-for-the-ipad.html) **Excel** for iPad is free as a read-only client for **Excel** spreadsheets.

Alternatives to purchasing a subscription to **Office 365** are available but each have their drawbacks.  (Formula editing, format retention, etc.)

- Google Sheets [[App Store link](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/google-sheets/id842849113?mt=8)] offers free editing of **Excel** files.  See documentation for details.
- Apple's own **Numbers** for iPad will open **Excel** files for editing but some of the functionality is limited.

Answer (score 1):

According to an [Apple forum answer](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/250043569?answerId=250073657022#250073657022), it may be possible to edit files on mobile devices such as iPhone, just by signing in to a Microsoft account, even *without* a Microsoft 365 subscription, with some [exceptions](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/when-do-i-need-a-microsoft-365-subscription-b6518311-893a-4a89-bfcd-bdc56bf52085?ui=en-us&rs=en-us&ad=us), including:

> Your mobile device is larger than 10.1”.
>
> You are creating, editing, and saving files to online business storage
> services such as:
>
> - Google Drive, Box, and other business storage
> - OneDrive for business
> - Dropbox for Business

Some features require a subscription. Without signing in, the files are treated as read-only.